# How a kinetic strike from orbit would look like?

Tags: science-fiction, kinetic-weapons, visuals

The impactor is a tungsten rod of 5 tons, moving at 0.015c, impacting a generic land spot on Earth.
Calculator of kinetic energy outputs that this will be equivalent to ~2 Mt nuclear warhead (if I'm not miscalculating), but would it actually *look* like a nuclear explosion going off? Will there be, besides a shockwave and a crater, things like a mushroom cloud and stuff?

Comment: Have you tried using a meteor impact calculator and read the description you get there?

Comment: The ones I found either treat the projectile as a loose piece of rock and say it will "disintegrate into fragments upon reentry", or won't allow enter numbers high enough for the density and speed, capping that at 80 km\s.

Comment: IIRC, mushroom clouds aren't specific to nuclear weapons, so my guess as to "will it look like a nuke" is "probably". At least in the sense you may get a mushroom cloud. However, you'll also likely get a nasty impact crater and material being thrown up from that which will look a bit like a "splash", albeit a *really big* one with dirt and rock rather than a more "traditional" liquid.

Comment: +1 to what @Matthew said. Mushroom clouds are just what you get when you have any sufficiently hot and large explosion and form due to the heated air rising (the "stem") and then cooling to form the "cap". They are not a "nuclear only" thing. Additionally though, there would probably be a bright line similar to what a sci-fi plasma bolt looks like that traces the path of where the impactor cut through the atmosphere

Comment: It would look exactly as any other 2 megaton explosion. The mechanism for releasing the energy is irrelevant. I am surprised that you didn't become acquianted with this trivial fact in the course of your diligent research. (And a small mushroom cloud appears at 0.001 megatons already; at 0.05 megatons you get the full-sized thing.)

Comment: @AlexP, yes and no. An air-bursting nuke (assuming we aren't talking about a shaped charge) is going to release that energy in all directions. A kinetic strike is initially going to be very focused in both position and direction, which is going to result in a bigger crater and more "splashing" than an omnidirectional above-ground release of the same amount of energy. A buried or ground-penetrating bomb is going to have still different characteristics. *Similar*, yes. *Exact*, no.

Comment: @Matthew - At 2MT, it's a distinction without a difference.  Tungsten is chosen for RFG strikes because of its density and melting point, but it still won't penetrate far enough to be appreciably different from a groundburst, unless the "average land" hit is unusually soft.

Comment: I must say, the mind **boggles** as to why this question got closed for being "off topic". Surely a visual description of what a hypervelocity kinetic impact would look like, is relevant to Worldbuilding? (even if the speed chosen for the impactor is a wee bit unrealistic).

Comment: What do you mean "the _speed_ is _unrealistic"?_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

0.015c is about 4500km/s

Not really enough speed for relativistic effect to make an appearance just yet.

Kinetic energy of your 5000kg impactor is some 5.056e16J
In easier to understand terms, energy equivalent to a nuclear bomb of 12.08 MegaTons

Assuming 90 degree entry, your projectile will traverse the last 100km of atmosphere in just 22 milliseconds.

It will superheat the air passage it passes through to quite ludicrous levels, without significantly slowing down at all.
When it strikes the ground, it will only penetrate a short distance, releasing all remaining energy in the form of a superheated explosion, **exactly** like a thermonuclear bomb, without the radioactivity. (0.015c is not enough for the impact to actually smash atoms, so your impactor is basically radioactivity-free)

Total energy: 12 Megatons
Energy lost in the air: 1.6 Megatons
Surface Impact energy: 10.4 Megatons

This [nifty meteor impact calculator](https://impact.ese.ic.ac.uk/ImpactEarth/cgi-bin/crater.cgi?dist=1000&distanceUnits=1&diam=.8&diameterUnits=1&pdens=19000&pdens_select=0&vel=4500&velocityUnits=1&theta=90&wdepth=&wdepthUnits=1&tdens=2750) tells it all.

What will it look like? Something like this.
Just add an additional narrow "beam" of superheated air along the incoming pathway of the Impactor. This beam will be very narrow, only expanding at the speed of sound thus less than 2 meters wide, yet radiating with the heat of 80 Hiroshima-sized nuclear explosions.
At the impact, you will have a very shallow subsurface explosion of some 10.4 Megatons, evolving almost identically to a surface hydrogen bomb explosion. The only example of such a large *surface* explosion would be the Castle Bravo nuclear test, which at 15Megaton is a tiny bit larger but very similar to your 10Megaton event.
(**the Castle Bravo nuclear test. For scale, that mushroom cloud at the time of this picture was about 5 miles wide, and 8 miles high**. It got to 130000ft altitude, and 62 miles in diameter, in just 10 minutes)
[image]

p.s.
It would not matter if your Impactor was 5 tons of Tungsten, or 5 tons of Marshmallow, the energy would be identical to about 10 decimals. Denser projectiles (actually density does not matter, frontal surface area is what counts) will deliver more into the surface, wider impactors would leave more of the energy in the air.
Normal orbital-speed Impactors are made of tungsten for the density and heat resistance, so they reach the surface intact. But that's at speed of below 20km/s. At your impactor's speed, *nothing* matters aside from the speed and mass of the projectile. Shape and material are utterly irrelevant.

Comment: At these velocities, regular approximations for impacts simply don't make sense, so I don't think that the impact effects calculator can give you any useful information about what happens above the surface of the earth. Also, the _density_ of the projectile is critically important to the effects of ablation in the atmosphere... 5 tonnes of marshmallow might not actually make it to the surface intact, and will produce quite a different fireball and crater.

Comment: It would be interesting to see what the electromagnetic spectrum of the impact flash would be, and whether [Flash blindness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_blindness) would be a concern.

Comment: @StarfishPrime at 4500km/s, marshmallow will definitely hit the ground. There simply is not enough time, enough matter between it and the ground. 5 tons of marshmallow would present about 4m2 of surface to the air along its path. That's about 40 tons of air its hitting, so very roughly the impact speed will be 4500*5/(40+5) =  500km/s. Yes, the marshmallow will shed 97% of its energy in the air, and will *still* hit the ground with the power of a decent strategic nuke.

Comment: @PcMan the problem is at this speed that you start having to think about mean free paths of neutral particles. The air doesn't just hit it. What you'll end up with is a broad plasma fireball producing effects more like a large airburst, rather than a dense projectile that will deliver much of its energy to a much smaller areas, shovelling much more of the ground around like a ground burst.

Comment: @Alexander The ground strike may or may not hide itself in its crater. The air path definitely will be glaringly visible. Spectrum? Whatever frequency air starts to become very transparent, for a column of air superheated to hundreds of millions of K. I expect very similar to a thermonuclear explosion, the x-rays will be absorbed, heating a wider column. the ultraviolet and al the way down to infrared will pass through, and scortch many an eyeball.

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR:

In as much as a nuke is just a lot of energy released in one place, it'll look like a nuke. It'll also look like a meteor, at least from a distance, but the impact fireball wil dominate its appearance at closer ranges.

- It'll definitely produce a big fireball.
- It'll probably produce a big crater like a nuke that's had a shallow burial.
- It'll definitely produce a mushroom cloud.
- It'll also produce a pillar of fire reaching from the surface at least 100km up. I'm not sure how thick or bright this will be.

---

> The impactor is a tungsten rod of 5 tons, moving at 0.015c

So, that's about 4500 km/s, or *really unnecessarily fast*. It is so far out of the realms of sensible speeds for macroscopic objects that you'll almost certainly not be able to find any serious information on how it will interact with the air or the ground. So, what follows is basically conjecture.

> Calculator of kinetic energy outputs that this will be equivalent to ~2 Mt nuclear warhead

I see a total kinetic energy of ~5x10<sup>16</sup> J. Given that a tonne of TNT yields ~4x10<sup>9</sup> J of boom, it seems to me that your calculator is a bit off, and should have suggested something more like *12* megatonnes equivalent.

> would it actually *look* like a nuclear explosion going off?

Well, yes and no.

Yes, because if your definition of "looks like a nuclear explosion" is "big bright fireball, shockwave, base surge, mushroom cloud" then pretty much any big bang will do that. You put enough energy into one spot and fluid dynamics will do the rest.

As mentioned in the comments, mushroom clouds are hardly unique to nukes... pay a visit to the [relevant wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mushroom_cloud) and you'll see a picture of a lovely mushroom cloud generated by a large volcanic eruption.

No, because a bunch of other weird effects are going to happen, too.

The kinetic energy of each tungsten atom is about 19 MeV which vastly exceeds the amount of energy required to ionise the whole thing, let alone the strength of the pitiful atomic bonds holding it together. Any interaction with any other atom (such as those the atmosphere or the Earth is made of) will be so violent that electrons and nuclei will be thrown off in all directions... the tip of the rod will basically turn into a dense plasma fireball at the uppermost fringes of the atmosphere. The kinetic energy works out as ~100 keV/nucleon, which is enough to generate gamma radiation on impact. It is *not* enough to transmute any nucleus, so there will be no fallout. There probably won't be enough gamma radiation to cause a high-altitude EMP. There will be some penetration of atmospheric nuclei and gamma radiation into the rod, but given the rod's considerable density and high atomic number the particles and radiation won't penetrate far enough to cause significant disruption of the projectile (though a lower density projectile may not remain intact by the time it gets to the ground).

Quite how high up the fireball will be visible, I've no idea. Regular meteors tend to light up at around [100 km](https://www.amsmeteors.org/meteor-showers/meteor-faq/#2), and your rod of doom will certainly be carving a very bright path at this altitude. It is travelling so fast that it'll get from the Kármán line to the surface in a little over a fiftieth of a second, so no motion will be apparent to human observers, but a bright vertical streak getting broader and brighter closer towards the ground will be visible from over 1000 km away.

Some proportion of the rod's mass and kinetic energy will be shed in the atmosphere. I've no idea how much, but given the total amount of energy involved even a small portion is going to have a yield equivalent to kilotonnes of TNT. Most of the energy seems likely to be shed closest to the ground. This will seem a little like a nuclear air blast, with a big bright dense blob of plasma except unlike a nice point-like nuke this will be a pillar of fire rather than a ball.

Given the sheer speed and density of the projectile, most of the air column in front of it will be compressed down to the ground as there simply isn't enough time for it to move out of the way. There's also not really enough time for a substantial amount of the projectile to be ablated away either, so you should disregard simulations of meteor ablation and brakeup in the atmosphere because they can't apply here.

Normally at this point I'd break out the old shaped-charge-jet hypervelocity penetration approximation, but that relies on both the penetrator and the target being treated as incompressible fluids... something that makes sense when the penetrator is moving at merely tens of kilometres per second, but not thousands.

Clearly, the rod is going to penetrate into the ground it will rapidly be ablated away as it does so, converting its kinetic energy into a fireball and into the rock around the impact. If it were a fluid penetrator, it would penetrate perhaps 2.5x to 3x its length into rocky ground, which for a rod-from-god like penetrator suggests somwhere between 12m and 20m depending on the rod's geometry. This may be deeper in this case because of the sheer ridiculous velocity of the projectile, but it seems unlikely to be more than an order of magnitude deeper. Deeper penetration spreads the energy out over a larger underground volume and seems likely to produce effects more like a volcanic blast, with huge quantities of ejecta being heaved into the air, but the impact with the surface means that this might not look much like a deep nuclear explosion. Shallower penetration should resemble a standard near-surface nuclear blast, with lots of energy being released in a very short period of time in a relatively small volume just below the surface in the form of a blob of very hot dense plasma.

As mentioned before, the kinetic energy of the penetrator is enough to release some gamma rays, so there will be a brief flash of radiation which will be rapidly absorbed in the air and rock around the impact site. Energies will not be high enough to cause any other kind of radiation or transmutation.